# How to install VisualVM plugin VisualGC - When Plugin Network Install blocked

Tags: visualvm

I'm using VisualVM to monitor a number of JAVA applications, I would like to install some of the plugins that are available within this app.. Unfortunately the 'Available Plugins' option does not work for myself, as I believe I may be blocked by the corporate proxy.

Any ideas how and where I can download an offline plugin, so that I can see this in 'VisualVM'.

Thanks,
Shaun.

Answer (score 28):

Plugins for offline VisualVM installations can be manually downloaded from the [Plugins Centers](https://visualvm.github.io/pluginscenters.html) page. Download the plugins as .nbm files. To install them in VisualVM do the following:

1. In VisualVM main menu choose Tools | Plugins, Plugins dialog is opened
2. Switch to Downloaded tab, click the Add Plugins... button, select downloaded plugin .nbm file(s) and click the Open button
3. Click the Install button, review and accept plugin license and wait for the plugin to be installed

Comment: Thanks discovered that after about 30 minutes of sending the post... But I was unable to answer my own question until 8 hours had passed.

Comment: Plugins Centers page is not available now

Comment: Apparently there are no plugins available to download anymore.

Comment: Plugins Centers page at http://visualvm.java.net/pluginscenters.html works fine for me.

Comment: VisualVM has now been shifted to github and so have been the plugins. https://visualvm.github.io/plugins.html

Comment: Weird thing, I downloaded the plugin (.nbm file), but it doesn't show up when I try to browse it from Downloaded > Add Plugins. In-fact, it doesn't show any files even if I change File format to All.
I am running VisualVM 2.1 on macOS BigSur. Anybody else faced this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Go to Tools > Plugins > Settings.
Edit URL to https://visualvm.github.io/uc/release139/updates.xml.gz.
Now plugins will be available & you can install online.

Answer (score 1):

1、Plugins Center:https://visualvm.github.io/pluginscenters.html

2、 Tools | Plugins

Answer (score 1):

On a production machine with no public internet connection, I was able to successfully install Luis-Miguel Alventosa's VisualVM-MBeans plugin by following this article dated November 19, 2012 and titled  "Installing VisualVM plug-ins into the shared directory"; http://veithen.github.io/2012/11/19/installing-visualvm-plugins-into-shared-directory.html; last accessed Jan 25, 2018.

"[The] article describes how to install VisualVM plug-ins into [a] shared installation directory instead of the user’s home directory. This is useful if the VisualVM installation is used by multiple users on the same system or if you want to create a custom VisualVM distribution with a set of pre-installed plug-ins. Actually the 'Force install into shared directories' option in the plug-in installation dialog (see the 'Settings' tab) should enable that, but the option doesn’t seem to work in VisualVM 1.3.4."
 
The following procedure can be used as a workaround:

1. Let VVM_HOME be the folder where VisualVM is installed.

   - On Windows Server 2012, a good choice might be C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop\VisualVM
2. Let PUBLIC be a machine with a public internet connection.
3. Let PRIVATE be a machine that lacks a public internet connection.​
4. On PUBLIC

   1. Install VisualVM.
   2. At least once, start VisualVM and exit.
   3. Remove (or backup) the user's VisualVM per-user configuration folder.

      - On Windows Server 2012, %APPDATA%\VisualVM\x.y.z.
      - On Linux, ${HOME}/.visualvm/x.y.z folder.
   4. Launch VisualVM and install the relevant plug-ins.  They will be placed into the user's VisualVM per-user configuration folder (the one deleted in the previous step).
5. On PRIVATE

   1. Install VisualVM.
   2. Create a new directory called custom (you may of course choose a different name if you want) under the VisualVM installation directory (i.e. at the same level as the platform and visualvm directories).
   3. ​Copy the following folder structures from ${HOME}/.visualvm/x.y.z to the custom directory e.g. %PROGRAMDATA%\VisualVM​\x.y.z (so that the resulting folder structure matches the one in platform and visualvm):

      - ​​​config/Modules
      - modules
      - update_tracking
   4. Edit the VVM_HOME/etc/visualvm.conf file enable a custom cluster folder: on Windows Server 2012, the line readsvisualvm_extraclusters=C:/ProgramData/VisualVM/1.4​
   5. Remove the user's VisualVM per-user configuration.
   6. If you start VisualVM now, the plug-ins you have copied to the custom folder should be available immediately.

Answer (score 0):

All sorted now...

If you goto the Plugin download site and download the required plugin, this by default is a ZIP file. Rename the ZIP to a NBM file and then you can manually install the plugin via the download tab.